# Django, use of ForeignKey's value within model

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I would like to make a system, which is photos belong to projects. I also enabled that I can upload a zipfile directly for a project and it will unzip and register the photos to the specified project. However, I am having troubles while defining the `Photo` class.

I need to get the value of `Project.file_zip.path` with the current instance for defining `img` field's `upload_to` attribute. However, when I tried like below, it returns with `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'file_path'`. How do I fix that?

```
class Project(models.Model):
....
owner=models.ForeignKey(User)
file_zip=models.FileField(upload_to='projects/%Y/%m/%d')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.project_name

def file_path(self):
    return re.search(re.search('[^\s]+(?=\.zip)', self.file_zip).group(0))

class Photo(models.Model):
    belongs_to=models.ForeignKey(Project)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/contact/python_project/all_bugs_will_reveal/'+belongs_to.file_path())
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to fields in a model within that same model's definition, as at the point when the definition is being read the class hasn't been defined yet.

The solution is to use a callable for `upload_to` - as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), this can be a function that is given the parameters `instance` and `filename`, so you can call `instance.filepath()` to get the correct path.

Comment: I am trying you follow your instructions but; either i defined the function invalid or i'm not calling it in the right way. `def project_path(instance, filename):  
return '%s/%s'%(instance.belongs_to.file_path,filename)` and `img=models.ImageField(upload_to=project_path())` returns with `TypeError: project_path() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`

Comment: should be `ImageField(upload_to=project_path)` - without the calling brackets. Otherwise, the function is called when the form is defined, with no parameters, rather than when a file is uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I actually wrote the right code but made a mistake somewhere else and while trying to find the bug, i changed that too. Works well now. Thanks.